# How to access existing AppBarButton and disable it

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there a way to access an existing `AppBarButton` and disable it programmatically when I'm on a specific page other than the MainPage?

```
<CommandBar Grid.Row="0">
    <CommandBar.Content>
        <Button 
            Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" 
            Name="BackButton" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Click="Back_Click"/>
    </CommandBar.Content>

    <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Name="ContactUs"/>
</CommandBar>
```

**Update**

**Main Page**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static AppBarButton MyAppBarButton;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Current = this;

        Frame_Main.Navigate(typeof(Frame1));

        MyAppBarButton = AppBarButtonSettings;
    }

    public static MainPage Current;

    private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        On_BackRequested();
    }

    private bool On_BackRequested()
    {
        if (Frame_Main.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame_Main.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void BackInvoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        On_BackRequested();
        args.Handled = true;
    }

    private void AppBarButtonContactUs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame_Main.Navigate(typeof(ContactUs));
    }
}
```

**Contact Us page**

```
public sealed partial class ContactUs: Page
{
    public ContactUs()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.IsEnabled = true;

        MainPage.MyAppBarButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, derive from your code, you could access `AppBarButton` with name in the code behind. for example:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContactUs.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

**Update**

You could make static `AppBarButton` to record  `ContactUs` and access with the page class name.

```
public static AppBarButton MyAppBarButton;

public TestPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyAppBarButton = ContactUs;
}
```

**Usage**

```
TestPage.MyAppBarButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: How can I access that from a Frame?

Comment: `The name 'ContactUs' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: ContactUs is your AppBarButton's name

Comment: You need set static `AppBarButton` in the the  MainPage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215361/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-macaronlover).